MicroStack Cluster login to juju fail
I am trying to install MicroStack on WSL2 ( Windows 11) ona fresh Ubunut-22.04 (Jammy) distribution.
I am following this tutorial https://microstack.run/docs/single-node.
My proplems start at the step
sunbeam cluster bootstrap --accept-defaults.
The previous steps did not yield obvious error messages.
The packages seem to be all installed
The exact error msg is:
> sunbeam cluster bootstrap --accept-defaults
An unexpected error has occurred. Please run 'sunbeam inspect' to generate an inspection report.
Error: End Of File (EOF). Exception style platform.
<pexpect.pty_spawn.spawn object at 0x7ff837efffa0>
command: /snap/openstack/576/juju/bin/juju
args: ['/snap/openstack/576/juju/bin/juju', 'login', '--user', 'admin']
buffer (last 100 chars): b''
before (last 100 chars): b'\x1b[91mERROR\x1b[0m no current controller\r\n'
after: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
match: None
match_index: None
exitstatus: None
flag_eof: True
pid: 7563
child_fd: 6
closed: False
timeout: 30
delimiter: <class 'pexpect.exceptions.EOF'>
logfile: None
logfile_read: None
logfile_send: None
maxread: 2000
ignorecase: False
searchwindowsize: None
delaybeforesend: 0.05
delayafterclose: 0.1
delayafterterminate: 0.1
searcher: searcher_re:
    0: re.compile(b'^please enter password')

It is not possible to run sunbeam inspect as this command also yields an error:
An unexpected error has occurred. Please run 'sunbeam inspect' to generate an inspection report.
Error: No juju controller configured for deployment better-hen.

I have already tried to get more information by running
sunbeam -v cluster bootstrap --accept-defaults

but I do not really understand what is wrong with my setup as I expect that after setting up the distribution on WSL I will only have to execute the commands from the tutorial.
THe error raises after the step:
Authenticating with Juju controller ...            DEBUG    Running step Login to Juju controller  

Before other juju errors like this at first appear:
[get] http+unix://%2Fvar%2Fsnap%2Fopenstack%2Fcommon%2Fstate%2Fcontrol.socket/1.0/config/JujuController, args={'allow_redirects': True}                                                                    service.py:121
           DEBUG    Clusterd service unavailable                                                                                                                                                                             deployment.py:96
                    Traceback (most recent call last):
                      File "/snap/openstack/576/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 715, in urlopen
                        httplib_response = self._make_request(
                      File "/snap/openstack/576/lib/python3.10/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 416, in _make_request
                        conn.request(method, url, **httplib_request_kw)
                      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1283, in request
                        self._send_request(method, url, body, headers, encode_chunked)
                      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1329, in _send_request
                        self.endheaders(body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
                      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1278, in endheaders
                        self._send_output(message_body, encode_chunked=encode_chunked)
                      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 1038, in _send_output
                        self.send(msg)
                      File "/usr/lib/python3.10/http/client.py", line 976, in send
                        self.connect()
                      File "/snap/openstack/576/lib/python3.10/site-packages/requests_unixsocket/adapters.py", line 41, in connect
                        sock.connect(socket_path)
                    ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

Is it a general problem that the tutorial is not usable as is when trying to set up MicroStack on WSL2 instead of native ubunut?
Or is there a sign that I set up the environment wrong?

Did you solve the issue ? I am facing the same.

I found this YouTube video which I followed. It was extremely helpful and easy to follow.
